# Why can't I delete two adjacent objects in hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using a Spring / Hibernate system, and I'm currently working on providing image management to my project.

I can create a parent, upload new images (well, I will be able to when I get to that...), but I can't delete two images next to each other. For example, I have eight images in my collection. If I select images 1,2,3 and click delete, 1 & 3 will delete, but 2 will linger. From my research, this seems to be from multiple threads, and using the [hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html#example-parentchild-bidir) I have added a `session.flush()` to my code, but it makes little difference.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
for (int i=0; i<images.size(); i++) {
    Image image = images.get(i);
    if (image.getRemove()) {
        page.getImages().remove(image);
        session.delete(image);
        session.flush();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Many thanks

Comment: For the record, I also tried session.clear() and session.close(), neither of which made a difference (session.close broke things even more).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your list of images:

```
A, B, C, D, E
```

You select the first, the second and the third (A, B, C), and mark them as "to be deleted".

At the first iteration, `i` is equal to 0, `size` is equal to 5, and you get the image at index 0 (A), which is marked for deletion, so the list becomes

```
B, C, D, E
```

At the second iteration, `i` is equal to 1, `size` is equal to 4, and you get the element at index 1 (C), which is marked for deletion, so the list becomes

```
B, D, E
```

At the third iteration, `i` is equal to 2, size is equal to 3, and you get the element at index 2 (E), which is not marked for deletion.

Conclusion: if you want to keep the same algorithm, start from the end of the list rather than starting from the beginning.